# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this code. Everything works fine - it gets data from DB but i cannot be returned. I'm posting it using jQuery.

```
Route::post('get/images', function(){
    $images = App\Images::where('realisation_id',Request::get('id'));
    return $images;
});
```

And it returns

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: You're not executing the query, simply building it.... and that's what you're returning for your route, a query object, you're not getting any data just usig the code you've posted.... get the data, and perhaps json encode it (otherwise you'll simply be trying to return a Collection object) before returning it

Comment: Well i just found this solution on other forum or Laravel documentation (I mean that solution i just shown here). I will try :)

Comment: Well when I used json_encode($images); it returns empty array but when I use return $images->count() it returns real ammount of datas gets from db.

Comment: Do not use PHP's `json_encode()` function as you are programming against a framework here. This is intended for people who has the same error and may think they can try this (wrong) solution. Please also consider accepting your own answer as valid.

Answer (score 5):

I'm stupid!

```
Route::post('get/images', function(){
    $images = App\Images::where('realisation_id',Request::get('id'))->get();
    return $images->toJson();
});
```

And everything is cool!

Comment: The `Collections` class in Laravel has the `toJson()` method always there. Directly returning the collection will not work as then the `Response` class will try to convert it to a string which exactly gives this error message. I had the same here with a JSON API (POST request). Link to 5.6: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-tojson

Comment: Now I saw, that I need to invoke `->get()` after `where()` (that returns the `Builder` instance only). And the error message is gone and JSON is being rendered properly.