# Error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have no idea on to why's my code's not working. Here's the code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $pk1 = Presensi::select('pukul1');
    $pk2 = Presensi::select('pukul2');

    $pk1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H-i-s', $pk1);
    $pk2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H-i-s', $pk2);
    $t_jam = $pk1->diffInHours($pk2);
    $presensi->update(
      [
        'jam_kerja_2' => $request -> jk1,
        'pukul2' => Carbon::now(),
        'Total' => $t_jam
      ]
    );
    return redirect()->route('admin.presensi.index');
```

And the model/migration looked like this

```
Schema::create('presensis', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('karyawan_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->String('nama');
        $table->String('jam_kerja_1', 10)->nullable();
        $table->Time('Pukul1')->nullable();
        $table->String('jam_kerja_2', 10)->nullable();
        $table->Time('Pukul2')->nullable();
        $table->String('Total')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: because  this is not how `createFromFormat` works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198127/object-of-class-illuminate-database-eloquent-builder-could-not-be-converted-to-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `Pukul1` and `Pukul2`'s type are `Time`, its format is `H:i:s`;

And you didn't take the time out. You need to use get the record out and get its attribute value.

So you need to change your code look like this:

```php
$pk1 = Presensi::select('pukul1')->first()->pukul1;
$pk2 = Presensi::select('pukul2')->first()->pukul2;

$pk1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $pk1);
$t_jam = $pk1->diffInHours($pk2);
```

Comment: Ok, now the error's gone. Thanks! But after the error's gone i wanted to update into the database with the following code, but it still gives me a null value
'
$presensi->update(
          [
            'jam_kerja_2' => $request -> jk1,
            'pukul2' => Carbon::now(),
            'Total' => $t_jam
          ]
        );
'

Comment: @IzzanA.Fu'ad do u means the column `Total` is nullable?

Comment: Yes the Total column is set to nullable, i wanted to update it so that the value becomes '$t_jam'

Comment: '$presensi is' the code for calling the model Presensi

'$presensi = Presensi::all();'
P.S. sorry that my reply isn't in a code format, still new to stack overflow and can't seem to figure out how to reply with a code

Comment: Well I do and I don't. The code before was set based on the 'Id' in the 'Presensi Table'. So it will automatically updates everytime I updated the 'jam_kerja_2'. But if you got a code so that will automatically updates all the rows in the database, i'll express my gratitude. Still a new programmer, so every knowledge counts for me.

Comment: @Izzan anyway, u can use `dd()`  to debug, it will helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By using select, you are not getting the information from the model yet. You need to use:

```
$pk1 = Presensi::select('pukul1')->first();
$pk2 = Presensi::select('pukul2')->first();
```

this way, you'll get the first element, in case you wanted all elements accomplishing the condition you have to use:

```
$pk1 = Presensi::select('pukul1')->get();
$pk2 = Presensi::select('pukul2')->get();
```